# ggplot2: coloring segments of single line with different colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot two lines and then color segments of a single line with different colors.
Here is a simple code:

```
temp <- data.frame(x = c(2, 4, 5, 5, 7, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9),
            y = c(3, 8, 4, 8, 8, 4, 9, 12, 5, 1),
            line = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
            color = c('c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'))

ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x, y, linetype = line, color = ???), data = temp)
```

I want to color segments of each line using the `color` factor. Any help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: just use the column name `color` in place of `???`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Each line in your sample data comprises 3 segments between 4 points. With 2 colours, how do you intend to split the colours among the segments?

Comment: Okay... after edits your lines now each have 4 segments between 5 points. Still not clear how you want the transition segments colored. Run `ggplot(temp, aes(x, y)) + geom_line(aes(linetype = line)) + geom_point(aes(color = color))`, we could make the lines between the red points red and the lines between the blue points blue. What color do you want the lines between the red and blue points??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this graph solve you problem?

`ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x, y, group = line, color = color), data = temp)`